# Ensure a TS interface has all enum's values as keys

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Assuming I have an enum:

```js
enum Cars {
  Volvo = 'Volvo',
  Hyundai = 'Hyundai',
  Kia = 'Kia',
  Tesla = 'Tesla'
}
```

I want to define an interface or a type, which should have **every** enum value as a key (types for them may be different or same):

```js
interface CarToFactory {
  [Cars.Volvo]: SwedishFactoryType,
  [Cars.Hyundai]: KoreanFactoryType,
  [Cars.Kia]: KoreanFactoryType,
  // <- Error: Missing Cars.Tesla
}
```

So adding a new car **should** throw an error unless you add a mapping to factory.

I tried to define an interface that extends `Record<Cars, Factory>`, but this doesn't give an error on missing property.

Also, the usage may not be obvious, but I have another interface with generic param, like:

```js
interface CarPassport<TCar extends Cars> {
  company: TCar,
  manufacturer: CarToFactory[TCar],
  year: number,
}
```

This is not a question about defining JS objects, I need to solve it on TS side

Comment: A simple Mapped Type should do the trick as shown in [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/KYOwrgtgBAwghgJwM5QN4CgpQGoHsA2AbrlALxQBEeRuFANJlABICeYIAJnAJZmWvsu3eowDS3OHwri4IrABVgSfJPIVFy2QwC+6dABcWAB2BQAooWAIW8BACVgARzDcEwDn1RQA2jCjcQWEQkAF0ALih2AGsQXAB3QO0Abj0AY1wQJH0oYEtrWwiLKxtEB2dXd090AHpqrCwAPybmhqgABQRcEwRDKAByX2CAOg0VEL7-FAhuJCQAgHN-QMMTIbXGQeQh6mJwyjkfWyQhgU4ePYoDzeOZC5Fk9CA). Does that address your question?

Comment: @Behemoth, thanks for the suggestion. This will work, for sure. But I wanted to avoid using JS objects, as I eventually need to have a CarToFactory mapping as a type

Comment: Sounds like you want a type-level `satisfies` operator. Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w8qarN) meet your needs? (And no, I can't make the error appear on the exact line you want, since we don't have much control over such things). If so, then I'll write up an answer or find a suitable duplicate target. If not, what am I missing? (Also, if there's anything important about `SwedishFactoryType` etc that is removed when I throw my own random types in there, then let us know by [edit]ing to make it a [mre] with definitions for all your types)

Answer (score 1):

Here I think the best approach is to split responsibilities:

- You will have an object (e.g. `carToFactory`) responsible for mapping `Cars` to `FactoryType`, and it will enable you to have a correct inference and not a generic type `FactoryType` in `CarPassport.manufacturer` as you would have using a simple `Record<Cars, FactoryType>`.
- You will have a type responsible to ensure that the entries of `carToFactory` match all the entries of `Cars`.
  The mapped type `{ [C in Cars]: typeof carToFactory[K] }` ensure that all `C` are in `carToFactory` and the `typeof carToFactory[K]` part allows typescript to infer the right `FactoryType`

```
enum Cars {
  Volvo = 'Volvo',
  Hyundai = 'Hyundai',
  Tesla = "Tesla"
}

interface FactoryType {
  brand: string
}

class VolvoFactoryType implements FactoryType {
  brand = "Volvo"
}
class HyundaiFactoryType implements FactoryType {
  brand = "Hyundai"
}

const carToFactory = {
  [Cars.Volvo]: new VolvoFactoryType(),
  [Cars.Hyundai]: new HyundaiFactoryType(),
} as const


export type CarToFactory<K extends Cars> = { [C in Cars]: typeof carToFactory[K] } // <- Error: Missing Cars.Tesla
// Expects carToFactory keys to be all the values of Cars

interface CarPassport<TCar extends Cars> {
  company: TCar,
  manufacturer: CarToFactory<TCar>[TCar],
  year: number,
}

const carPassport: CarPassport<Cars.Hyundai> = {
  company: Cars.Hyundai,
  manufacturer: carToFactory[Cars.Hyundai],
  year: 2024
}
const shouldBeHyundaiFactoryType = carPassport.manufacturer
const carPassportInvalid: CarPassport<Cars> = {
  company: Cars.Hyundai,
  manufacturer: Cars,
  year: 2024
}
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAwghgJwM5QN4CgpQGoHsA2AbrlALxQDkeRuFANJlABICeYIAJnAJZmWvsu3eowAqwJPjh8AROMlwZ6AL7p03EABdgCAGZwAxsCgAxQ5twIWolgAdjGLACMEcTgC4oSTQg0BzFTUDKSQUamIzAwsrG3sobghbfGAIUE0USOjrOwdGFzcOWXDcJVVguFDmNk4eTMtsuISklLSM83rY3OdXTlkBGu5SoNwQbygDRFFcOqs+RygAbXhkADpigF1PEGAAdxwCCPaYnIAKAEoGLCXEJBX+oU2obb372qOG4HOGZSgK8ZHvGp0MAAB62SyaKCaHKwSbTd4AHgA0lBQdpOChlkgAHxzRYweIgWHIR7Q+y4XTjOEzFgLJHrKA-AD0TKgCIAtFAAKIIBCWTwAWW4oX8xNu8ik6BZ3LBwCiKAmCCmNKgAGtgCwUBYoE5jHB8PgoQALYyEfVgCRQClitQabR6QzGZYABQqSHBCE0CNEy1RIPRHExN1x8wMuESbhYnh9iEuUAgbjA+iiYAQOk8y2ViJjCGxCxz6zjLGAiC2kF1CG+w1GkMVrtCHs0GcQ9fdEIRWLu1SEuPIofDtkjzdWr24cYT4GTmlT6apSvhUXq1xH3Z4hcYxdLUAATAAGbcAFkCYZrXiNuDA+A4ACFgKOaZ0+HW3Y2VhOk+YZwh0Cexs+GxCACSIBmvg3AcMOraNh2wZzIwYYRiAUZil2gg8OOiZTl+w5IEWJYIJ4e6HioQA) there is a playground with the code

Comment: But you have two type errors, and I think this is the same error he's receiving.

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question, but I think he's asking how to receive errors if `carToFactory` is incomplete (first error) and how to use the `carToFactory` type in another interface (second error is expected because `manufacturer` shouldn't be of type `Cars`

Comment: This is something that I currently have in mind. Unfortunately, "string" is too wide in this case. What I need is having a JS variable `passport` of type `CarPassport<Car.Kia>` automatically means passport.manufacturer is `KoreanFactoryType`. With your suggestion it is a string.

Comment: @ArtemYankin you should define what `yourDesiredType` is. For example all the `FactoryTypes` could extend a base `FactoryType`. I'll update the playground to make it achieve the desired inference

Comment: @ArtemYankin the answer should now answer all your questions. Please modify the question highlighting your inference needs as well!

Answer (score 0):

It's an excellent question, here are some ideas that I think about it

```
enum Cars {
  Volvo = "Volvo",
  Hyundai = "Hyundai",
  Kia = "Kia",
  Tesla = "Tesla",
}

interface SwedishFactoryType {}
interface KoreanFactoryType {}
interface AmircanFactoryType {}

type FactoryType = SwedishFactoryType | KoreanFactoryType | AmircanFactoryType;

interface CarList extends Record<Cars, FactoryType> {}

const carList: CarList = {
  [Cars.Volvo]: {},
  [Cars.Hyundai]: {},
  [Cars.Kia]: {},
  [Cars.Tesla]: {},
};
```